# Spring Cloud Kafka: Connection refused: no further information

Tags: java, spring-boot

I´m new to Kafka and am wrestling with this annoying problem:

here is the exception I got when sending request with Postman

```
{ "timestamp": "2022-02-24T14:22:36.851+00:00", "status": 401, "error": "Unauthorized", "path": "/api/v1/customers/barbie" }
```

Concept is simple: 2 Apps separatedly - 1 acts as Producer, 1 as Consumer, the object being sent back & forth is "Message".

Here is the Producer: "Customer"

CustomerConfig: I use SOAP + Spring WS

```
@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class CustomerConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
        servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/ws/*");
    }

    @Bean(name = "customer")
    public DefaultWsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition(XsdSchema customerSchema) {
        DefaultWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
        wsdl11Definition.setPortTypeName("CustomerPort");
        wsdl11Definition.setLocationUri("/ws");
        wsdl11Definition.setTargetNamespace("http://spring.io/guides/gs-producing-web-service");
        wsdl11Definition.setSchema(customerSchema);
        return wsdl11Definition;
    }

    @Bean
    public XsdSchema countriesSchema() {
        return new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("customer.xsd"));
    }

    @Bean
    @LoadBalanced
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(){
        return new RestTemplate();
    }

    @Bean public KafkaTemplate<String, Message> kafkaTemplate(ProducerFactory<String, Message> producerFactory) {
        return new KafkaTemplate(producerFactory);
    }

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, Message> producerFactory(KafkaProperties kafkaProperties) {
        Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.MAX_BLOCK_MS_CONFIG, 30000);
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory(kafkaProperties.buildProducerProperties());
    }

    @Value("${spring.kafka.producer.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootstrapAddress;

    @Bean
    public KafkaAdmin kafkaAdmin() {
        Map<String, Object> configs = new HashMap<>();
        configs.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
        return new KafkaAdmin(configs);
    }

    /*
    @Bean
    public NewTopic processTopic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("I´m a Barbie girl").partitions(2).build();
    }
     */
}
```

CustomerController: The Endpoint, in REST. For the sake of Testing. The real SOAP Endpoint is commented out in the meantime

```
    @Slf4j
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("api/v1/customers")

public class CustomerController {
    @Autowired
    private CustomerService the_service;

    @GetMapping("/barbie")
    public String doSomething() {
        the_service.sendSomeBS();
        return "It works, how bad ass is that, bitches!!!";
    }
}
```

CustomerService

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Service("FeignImpl")
@Slf4j
public class CustomerService {

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, Message> kafkaTemplate;

    private final CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    private final MessageRepository messageRepository;

     public Customer findOneCustomer(String customerName) throws NotFoundException {

        return customerRepository.findCustomerByFirstName(customerName)
                .orElseThrow(
                        () -> new NotFoundException(String.format("User %s not found", customerName))
                );

     }

     public void sendSomeBS(){
        System.out.println("Afjasdgjkdhjkgsdfklgh");
        Message to_send = messageRepository.findMessageByMessageName("Bla").get();
        kafkaTemplate.send("Barbie", to_send);
     }
}
```

"application.yml" of the producer app

```
server:
  port: 9090

spring:
  application:
    name: customer
  datasource:
    password: 
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
    username: 
  jpa:
    generate-ddl: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
        format_sql: true
    show-sql: true
  kafka:
    producer:
      bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
      key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      value-serializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer

eureka:
  client:
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka
  instance:
    prefer-ip-address: true
    hostname: localhost
```

The "Message" object being sent back & forth

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Entity
public class Message {

    @Id
    private Integer id;

    private String something;

    private String messageName;
}
```

*** The consumer: "Transaction"

** TransactionConfig

```
@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class TransactionConfig {
    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
        servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/ws/*");
    }

    @Bean(name = "transaction")
    public DefaultWsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition(XsdSchema transactionSchema) {
        DefaultWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
        wsdl11Definition.setPortTypeName("TransactionPort");
        wsdl11Definition.setLocationUri("/ws");
        wsdl11Definition.setTargetNamespace("http://spring.io/guides/gs-producing-web-service");
        wsdl11Definition.setSchema(transactionSchema);
        return wsdl11Definition;
    }

    @Bean
    public XsdSchema countriesSchema() {
        return new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("transaction.xsd"));
    }

    @Bean
    @LoadBalanced
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(){
        return new RestTemplate();
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, Message> consumerFactory(KafkaProperties kafkaProperties){
        Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
        configProps.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        configProps.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "group_id");
        configProps.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        configProps.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
        configProps.put(JsonDeserializer.TRUSTED_PACKAGES, getClass().getName());
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(kafkaProperties.buildConsumerProperties());
    }

    @Value("${spring.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootstrapAddress;

    @Bean
    public KafkaAdmin kafkaAdmin() {
        Map<String, Object> configs = new HashMap<>();
        configs.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
        return new KafkaAdmin(configs);
    }

    /*
    @Bean
    public NewTopic processTopic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("I´m a Barbie girl").partitions(2).build();
    }
     */
}
```

** TransactionService

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Service("FeignImpl")
@Slf4j
public class TransactionService {

    private final TransactionRepository transactionRepository;

    public Transaction findOneTransaction(String message) throws NotFoundException {
        return transactionRepository.findByMessage(message).orElseThrow(
                () -> new NotFoundException(String.format("Transaction with message %s not found", message))
        );
    }

    @KafkaListener(topics = "Barbie", groupId = "group_id")
    public void consume(Message message) {
        // Gut, gut
        System.out.println("Tasting Barbie " + message.getSomething());
    }
}
```

** "application.yml" of the consumer

```
server:
  port: 9095

spring:
  application:
    name: transaction
  datasource:
    password: 
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
    username: 
  jpa:
    generate-ddl: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
        format_sql: true
    show-sql: true
  kafka:
    consumer:
      bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
      group-id: group_id
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
      key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      value-deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
      properties:
        spring.json.trusted.packages: "com.test.transaction"

eureka:
  client:
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka
  instance:
    prefer-ip-address: true
    hostname: localhost
```

Both apps are connected by EurekaServer, published by Gateway under the same URL "localhost:9091". Only a small extra header "SOAPAction" is required to tell the Gateway which app is targeted.

The process looks like this: Calling the "doSomething()" REST Endpoint of CustomerController to trigger the messaging.

But somehow I can´t get authorized.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the log of my "Customer" when I send a Request

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans": Connection refused: no further information; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:785) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.zipkin2.ZipkinRestTemplateWrapper.doExecute(ZipkinRestTemplateWrapper.java:69) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:660) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.zipkin2.RestTemplateSender.post(RestTemplateSender.java:151) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.zipkin2.RestTemplateSender$HttpPostCall.doExecute(RestTemplateSender.java:169) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.zipkin2.RestTemplateSender$HttpPostCall.doExecute(RestTemplateSender.java:159) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at zipkin2.Call$Base.execute(Call.java:391) ~[zipkin-2.23.0.jar:na]
    at zipkin2.reporter.AsyncReporter$BoundedAsyncReporter.flush(AsyncReporter.java:299) ~[zipkin-reporter-2.16.1.jar:na]
    at zipkin2.reporter.AsyncReporter$Flusher.run(AsyncReporter.java:378) ~[zipkin-reporter-2.16.1.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:542) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:597) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:178) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:498) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:603) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:246) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:351) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:373) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1309) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1242) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:1057) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:76) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:66) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:776) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    ... 9 common frames omitted
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean "authorized"? Is Kafka actually running? How?

Comment: Kafka is running, yes, on my localhost:9092.  And here is the exception I got when sending request with Postman "{
    "timestamp": "2022-02-24T14:22:36.851+00:00",
    "status": 401,
    "error": "Unauthorized",
    "path": "/api/v1/customers/barbie"
}"

Comment: So, your error comes from Spring's FilterChain at some point but I see nothing in the code you've provided that sets up any authentication. I'm also removing the Kafka tag since that's not part of the problem here

Comment: Thank you. That´s the thing: I haven´t set up anything regarding Spring Security  :(

Answer (score 0):

`:9411/api/v2/spans`  is referring to a Zipkin address, probably because you're using Spring Cloud Sleuth somewhere.

If you want to remove those logs, ether disable tracing or setup Zipkin locally as well.

However, this shouldn't affect your authorization error. I assume that would originate at the Eureka server since nothing in your Spring code seems to be setup for authentication/authorization

Comment: Thank you. Yes, the Zipkin wasn´t active. The problem is, turned out, Spring Boot implements as Default "SecurityAutoConfiguration.class" , which should be deactivated in my case.